# Infinite set as a countably infinite union of infinite disjoint subsets

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

I am struggliglng with an exercise as the title.

I have been able to get to a proof, if the set is infinitely countable, but I am having problems on infinite uncountable sets.

Any thoughts on how to think about it?

EDITED: Added the word 'disjoint' and "countably"

Comment: If the set say S is uncountable then you can get a subset of S say, S' which is countable and infinite, Now $S= S \cup (S-S')$.Note that  $S-S'$ is uncountable thus infinite. Since you have a proof for countable case, you can express S' as a infinite union of infinite sets, you can say S= infinite union of infinite sets union S-S'

Comment: What I am saying is, you have $S' =\cup_\alpha G_\alpha$(where G's are infinite sets and index set is also infinite.) then S= $\cup_\alpha G_\alpha \cup (S-S')$, $(S-S')$ is also infinite.

Comment: @bof Indeed, the exercise, as written in the book, states disjoint subsets.

Answer (score 3):

Given an infinite set $S$, for any element $x\in S$ the subset $S\setminus\{x\}$ is also infinite. By assumption, $S$ has infinitely many elements, therefore the union
$$\bigcup_{x\in S}(S\setminus\{x\})=S$$
is an infinite union of infinite subsets of $S$.

**Edit:**

With the added requirement of countably many disjoint sets, the following needs the axiom of choice (via the well-ordering theorem).

According to the well-ordering theorem, the set $S$ is in bijection with a von-Neumann ordinal. Be $\phi:\alpha\to S$ such a bijection.

Since you say you already have the proof for countable $S$, let's further assume that $S$ (and therefore $\alpha$) is uncountable.

Now it is possible to write each ordinal uniquely as sum $\lambda + n$ of a non-successor (i.e. zero or limit) ordinal $\lambda$ and a finite ordinal $n$.

Define
$$\alpha_n = \{\rho\in\alpha | \rho = \lambda + n \text{ for some non-successor ordinal $\lambda$}\}$$

Clearly there are countably many such $\alpha_n$, one for each $n\in\omega$. Moreover, quite obviously the different $\alpha_n$ are disjoint, their union is $\alpha$, and each of them is clearly infinite (because otherwise $\alpha$ would be countable).

Now we get the desired union for $S$ by simply using the images of $\alpha_n$ under the bijection $\phi$:
$$S = \bigcup_{n\in\omega} \{\phi(x)|x\in \alpha_n\}$$

Comment: That was a great answer! Excuse me for not mentioning that I am looking to find disjoint subsets. I have just edited the question.

Comment: @XuUserAC: See the updated answer.